# How in C++ can I get a number back to its normal form after using scientific property from setiosflags() functoin in #include "iomanip" library

Tags: c++

I am writing a code in C++ following a totorial. and the instractor teached us setiosflags function which is part of #include "iomanip" library. he used the scientific property on the number that I want display. but in my case it prints out the address not the scientific Number and after that when I use fixed property for the same function the number do not convert again back to the normal form. it just stays on the form of scientific  property how can I get it back to its normal or fixed form.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include "cmath"
#include "iomanip"
using namespace std;
int main() {
// a problem when I change it to scientific I could not get itback
cout<<"|"<<setw(20)<<142.1<<"|\n";
cout<<"|"<<setw(20)<<setiosflags(ios::left)<<142.1<<"|\n";
cout<<"|"<<setw(20)<<setiosflags(ios::scientific)<<142.1<<"|\n";
cout<<"|"<<setw(20)<<setiosflags(ios::fixed)<<142.1<<"|\n";
cout<<"|"<<setw(20)<<setiosflags(ios::right)<<142.1<<"|\n";
return 0;
}


output:
|             142.100|
|142.100             |
|0x1.1c33333333333p+7|
|0x1.1c33333333333p+7|
|0x1.1c33333333333p+7|
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/resetiosflags

Comment: "How in C++ can I get a number back to its normal form" - Nitpick: The *number* hasn't changed. A number it what it is, regardless of how you represent it. Only your *presentation* of the number has changed - the number itself is unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::defaultfloat` to get back to the default output format.

```
cout << "|" << setw(20) << std::defaultfloat << 142.1 << "|\n";
```

See it working at https://ideone.com/YvsLW4.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed for more info on the subject.

Comment: Thanks alot it helped to get my number back to its normal form but the output of  the scietific property is an address not the number it self. do you know what the problem is?

Comment: @ahmed, use of `setiosflags(ios::scientific)` and `setiosflags(ios::fixed)` causes the numbers to be written in hex. Hop over to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags and read the description beside `scientific` and `fixed` in the page. Use of `std::scientific` and `std::fixed` seems to avoid that. See https://ideone.com/g4G8g4.

Comment: Thanks alot, I looked in the link you send. and there I read that this form of output: | 0x1.1c33333333333p+7 | is called hexfloat.
and it is from #include "sstream" library

Comment: and I do not nead to use setiosflags function to change my output format,
I can simply type like  this :______cout<< "The number 0.01 in scientific: " << std::scientific << 0.01 << '\n'

Comment: So my problem actually is when I try to use scientific form of output using setiosflags it put it in the hexfloat form not the scientific form we now like this 
| 1.421000e+02        |, so why it print it out in hexfloat format rather than normal scientific format

Comment: @ahmed, it uses hex output only when both `setiosflags(ios::scientific)` and `setiosflags(ios::fixed)` are used. If you use just `setiosflags(ios::scientific)` it does not use hex. I do not know why the standard library's behavior is defined that way.

Comment: and it print out the hexfloat format without the combination with fixed also

Answer (score 2):

The opposite of setiosflags is resetiosflags. (The scientific and fixed flags are not linked/toggled togther -- they're independent).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include "cmath"
#include "iomanip"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    // a problem when I change it to scientific I could not get itback
    cout<<"|"<<setw(20)<<142.1<<"|\n";
    cout<<"|"<<setw(20)<<setiosflags(std::ios_base::left)<<142.1<<"|\n";
    cout<<"|"<<setw(20)<<setiosflags(std::ios_base::scientific)<<142.1<<"|\n";
    cout<<"|"<<setw(20)<<resetiosflags(std::ios_base::scientific)<<142.1<<"|\n";
    cout<<"|"<<setw(20)<<setiosflags(std::ios_base::right)<<142.1<<"|\n";
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
|               142.1|
|142.1               |
|1.421000e+02        |
|142.1               |
|               142.1|
```

Comment: Thanks alot it helped to get my number back to its normal form but the output of  the scietific property is an address not the number it self. do you know what the problem is?

Comment: It works OK as-is for me, but see @R Sahu's comments above about switching from ios:: to std:: for the flags (I'll edit my answer to that as well)